# ESP8266 01 wifi module

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I have a weird problem  , as I.m trying to connect to esp8266 01 with Arduino Uno when i try sending commands from the serial it doesn't work but if i send it in a function in the setup phase it works

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial esp8266(2, 3);

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
esp8266.begin(9600);
delay(1000);
//sendData("AT", 1000);
//sendData("AT+CWMODE=1", 1000);
}

void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
if(esp8266.available()) // check if the esp is sending a message
  {
      while(esp8266.available())
      {
          // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window
          char c = esp8266.read(); // read the next character.
          Serial.write(c);
      }
  }
  if(Serial.available())
  {
    delay(1000);
    String command="";
    while(Serial.available()) // read the command character by character
    {
        command+=(char)Serial.read();
    }
    esp8266.println(command); // send the read character to the esp8266
  }
}

void sendData(String command, const int timeout) {
 String response = "";
 esp8266.println(command);
 long int time = millis();
 while ((time + timeout) > millis())
   while (esp8266.available()) {
     char c  = esp8266.read();
     response += c;
    }
 Serial.println(response);
}
```

Comment: try to print back to Serial the `command` variable

Comment: i did , the command was fine just AT command it responds with busy p... then error

Comment: do you have CR/LF in Serial Monitor? then replace `println(command)` with `print(command)`

Comment: sorry , i don't know about CR/LF . i tried print and it just responds with error

Comment: in Serial Monitor one of the settings is line ending. LN & CR

Comment: ooh , i found it it's set to Newline

Comment: AT firmware requiers \r\n (CR/LF). println adds it. so you need to set it in Serial Monitor or don't set in Serial Monitor and use println. (\n\r\n was the worst combination)

Comment: i changed the settings to Both NL& CR and now it works ... thanks man

Comment: well ... another problem appears ... AT+CWJAP="SSID" , "password" dont work ... this i have tried with send data function and serial monitor i don't know what is the problem although that AT+CWLAP works

Comment: you have a space after the comma? you still print back the command? is it complete?

Comment: AT+CWJAP="ssid", "password"     that's exactly how i wrote it

Comment: remove the space after the comma

Comment: tried it and many other ways i tried space after and before comma , and removed all spaces ... nothing works

Comment: did you send CWMODE first?

Comment: omg .... finally it's connected .. many thanks you are great

Comment: ya i did but my problem was a space before = i guess

Comment: i wanted to do that from the beginning but i can't you added comments not answers add an answer so i can upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take your code as a test sketch and will not comment on the terrible way you read Serial input.

The AT firmware requires \r\n as command ending characters. You can set them in Serial Monitor as option LN & CR, but then use `print` to send the command to esp8266.

Or set in Serial Monitor "No line ending" and let in sketch the `println` to send the command. `println` adds \r\n to printed string.

If you had only "New line" set in Serial Monitor and used `println` the resulting command was for AT firmware disturbing "AT\n\r\n".

Comment: i don;t know the right way to read serial input can u please demonstrate as i took the code from internet .

Comment: I fixed that problem now i send AT commands and it responds well my problem now is connecting to an access point